# Android why apps works on Android Studio with real devices but buggy after upload to store

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Developed a big Android app and tested on emulators all versions from 4.1.1 to 10 and on real devices original brands also all versions from 4.1.1 to 9.0 no bugs appeared. However when uploaded to the store many bugs appeared. For example the app is English / Arabic, on real test devices with android studio worked fine but on the store below Android 9.0 did not switch to Arabic. Another bugs like Notification on Android 5.1.1 showed crash.

My question in general, what makes Android apps works fine on real devices connected to Android Studio while the same real devices shows bugs when same app installed from the play store, what does google do on the code to do this, what else can I do instead of uploading beta versions to final test.

Comment: [My Opinion] I think it is better to test your app on device rather than emulator through android developer setting.

Comment: did you use proguard?

Comment: @Goion as I said in the post, I tested on real devices original brands Samsung and Huwaui.

Comment: '
@RofieSagara I disabled proguard as it causes problems to me:
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the multilanguage add this below code in your build.gradle file.

```
android{
       bundle {

    language {
        enableSplit = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the use of the enableSplit = false, what will it do exactly?

Comment: When you used the multiple language features in your application, then according to the new Android app bundle functionality it will split resources according to device configuration.